# Azure DevOps API - Update Testcase Automation status

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to update a testcase 'Automation status' to 'Automated' using Azure DevOps API?

Comment: Have you finish your solution. I'm building something similar but not only the automation status, also sync up the test step from source code to Azure devops testcase @Andrey Kudin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update the `Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestId`, `Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestStorage`, and `Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestName` fields. Then Azure DevOps will update automation status to Automated. Here is example with [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/):

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static readonly string TFUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/<your_org>/";
        static readonly string UserAccount = "";
        static readonly string UserPassword = "";
        static readonly string UserPAT = "<your_pat>"; //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops

        static WorkItemTrackingHttpClient WitClient;
        static BuildHttpClient BuildClient;
        static ProjectHttpClient ProjectClient;
        static GitHttpClient GitClient;
        static TfvcHttpClient TfvsClient;
        static TestManagementHttpClient TestManagementClient;
        static TeamHttpClient TeamClient;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                ConnectWithPAT(TFUrl, UserPAT);

                Dictionary<string, object> fields = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                fields.Add("Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestId", "123");
                fields.Add("Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestStorage", "MyClassName");
                fields.Add("Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestName", "NameOfAutomatedTest");

                UpdateWorkItem(test_case_id, fields);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
                if (ex.InnerException != null) Console.WriteLine("Detailed Info: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Stack:\n" + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        static WorkItem UpdateWorkItem(int WIId, Dictionary<string, object> Fields)
        {
            JsonPatchDocument patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument();

            foreach (var key in Fields.Keys)
                patchDocument.Add(new JsonPatchOperation()
                {
                    Operation = Operation.Add,
                    Path = "/fields/" + key,
                    Value = Fields[key]
                });

            return WitClient.UpdateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument, WIId).Result;
        }


        static void InitClients(VssConnection Connection)
        {
            WitClient = Connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
            BuildClient = Connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
            ProjectClient = Connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();
            TeamClient = Connection.GetClient<TeamHttpClient>();
            GitClient = Connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();
            TfvsClient = Connection.GetClient<TfvcHttpClient>();
            TestManagementClient = Connection.GetClient<TestManagementHttpClient>();
        }

        static void ConnectWithDefaultCreds(string ServiceURL)
        {
            VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(ServiceURL), new VssCredentials());
            InitClients(connection);
        }

        static void ConnectWithCustomCreds(string ServiceURL, string User, string Password)
        {
            VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(ServiceURL), new WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential(User, Password)));
            InitClients(connection);
        }

        static void ConnectWithPAT(string ServiceURL, string PAT)
        {
            VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(ServiceURL), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, PAT));
            InitClients(connection);
        }
    }
}
```

The result:

1. The test method info

[image]

2. The automation status info:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It's working for me. I also was able to found this solution.

Comment: @Andreykudin That's great to know **Shamrai's** answer helps to resolve your issue, consider [accepting it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) if it's the right answer to your question. Just a reminder ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to update a testcase 'Automation status' to 'Automated'
>   using Azure DevOps API?

Sorry for any inconvenience. As I know this is one **not supported** scenario for Azure Devops Rest API.

The Rest Api do provide one [WorkItem-Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) api to update the fields in one work item. And we can use it to update the `Automation status` to `Planned` or `Not Automated`.

[image]

However `Automated` status is unique. Different from other fields, this option can't be enabled unless there's test associated with it. You can check [Andy's gif](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/513527/view.html) here to get a better understanding.

And to [associate test with test case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops), we must use Visual Studio to do that. This cannot be done from the Azure Devops Test hub. That's why Azure Devops Rest API can't enable the `Automated` status in your scenario. (Only if we use VS to associate test with the online test case can this field set as Automated! )

Hope my answer helps to resolve your puzzle :)